# how to call a base class non default constructor from the instantion of the derived class?

Tags: c#

i have a base class and derived class. Base class has 2 constructor as follows.

```
    class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM BASE class");
    }

    public A(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base : parameter 1");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM DERIVED class");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is **I AM BASE CLASS** and **I AM DERIVED CLASS**
my requirement is, when B is instantiaded, then the base class's parametrized constructor should get called instead of the default constructor. 
Please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: you can add base keyword to the default constructor.

Comment: use constructor initializer list in this case then.

Comment: The code is the question is C#, not C++

Comment: @Sean it was originally tagged as C#, but ismail baig had mistakenly re-tagged it as C++ (and has now fixed the error him/herself)

Answer (score 1):

Use the intializer list in the constructor for B

```
class B : A
{
    public B() : A(42)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM DERIVED class");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the `B` constructor like this:

```
 public B() : base(1)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("I AM DERIVED class");
 }
```

NOTE: I've changed the question tag to C# as the code you've given is C#, not C++.

Comment: Its called as the **member initializer list**

Answer (score 0):

```
class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM DERIVED class");
    }
    public B(int x)
    : A(x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM DERIVED class (with a parameter)");
    }
}
```